Two SQL databases combined
I have an accounting firm client that recently acquired another firm. They both use the IDENTICAL software products that utilize a SQL server, so the table structure should be identical or nearly identical.
Can I combine the two files into a single file? I'd be happy to read some documentation, but the term "merge" sends me in many directions.
I'm lightly skilled; familiar with SSMS and basic queries.

As per one key point in Erik's answer - you should definitely discuss requirements with the software vendor.  If it's software that's capable of dealing with multiple different companies / legal entities, then you should certainly be able to have both companies operating within a single database.  That said, it is no way a task for someone "lightly skilled" or "familiar with basic queries" ......

nosireebob
You can't just merge SQL Server databases together at the file level. It's not a storage format friendly to that sort of thing, like combining text files, etc. Likewise, you may not even be able to insert data from one database to the other without a lot of considerations.
If the software uses identity columns, and those identity columns function as more than just surrogate keys, you would have to account for that overlap and make sure that any entities moved into database A from database B retain the correct relationships across tables. You'd also need to make sure that any entity identifiers aside from those do the same.
What that means is that if you already have client 12345 in both databases, and the highest client number is 99999 in database A, you would have to add 10000 to any client numbers in database B. In the case of identity columns, which can't directly be updated, you would have to do that while inserting them. It would get quite messy quite quickly.
Now rinse and repeat for anything else that uniquely identifies a thing, like an invoice number, a payment receipt, or any number of other ledger-y things.
Any alterations would also have to account for foreign key relationships as well, if you were to try to insert data from one database into another. You may have to correctly order each individual insert from one table to another across databases so that you don't end up with them erroring out due to some constraint violation.
To continue with client 12345, you may not be able to insert data for them because it would violate a unique constraint in the client table.
It's also fairly common for accounting software to have the option to print/send invoices. If anyone is holding on to copies of them, and they call up with a question, things might get right confusing for anyone trying to look that invoice number up in the combined system. You'd need to either maintain a lookup table to map any imported entries, or maintain a historical copy of one of the databases to look up unchanged data from.
You'll want to ask the accounting software company if they have any tools designed for this task. It's highly likely that it has been requested at some point. If it hasn't, getting their help with it would probably save you quite a bit of time and headaches and data quality issues and an extended employment search.
If you choose to go it on your own, you should back up and restore both databases to a server far away from production to test data migrations so you don't end up with anything getting completely borked with live data where people might have expectations around "correct results" and other things that accountants tend to care about.
